# Fundamental gravitational wave frequency for Kerr black holes?

Tags: gravitational-waves, kerr-metric

Just as the usual rotating pulsars (neutron stars) have fundamental frequency(ies) tied to the rotational frequency, does it happen in Kerr black holes too? What are the frequencies of rotating Kerr black hole gravitational waves? What to we know about the relative strain between non-rotating vs. rotating black holes?

Comment: Lone Kerr black holes don't emit gravitational waves? What waves are you asking about?

Comment: The frequencies of Kerr black holes...and if it is has harmonics and they have a fundamental tone just like binaries (f=2 times orbital frecuency) or the one in continous gravitational wave emission from neutron stars. Should I clarify this point?

Comment: Search for “quasinormal modes kerr black hole”.

Comment: To expand on @HTNW's comment -- isolated neutron stars can emit gravitational waves if they have a nonzero *ellipticity* -- meaning, essentially, that there is a small "mountain" on the neutron star that breaks the azimuthal symmetry about the rotation axis, leading to a time-dependent quadrupole moment. The Kerr solution is azimuthally symmetric, so unlike an isolated neutron star, an isolated Kerr BH *cannot* radiate gravitational waves. To get gravitational waves with a Kerr BH you need a binary system or to perturb the BH somehow, leading to quasinomral mode transients.

Comment: @Andrew So, even Kerr black holes that are NOT spherically symmetric can not radiate gravitational waves? I thought a sufficient condition for GW emission was non-sphericity, and since Kerr BH are oblate rotating space-times, I thought we should have GW emission. So, unless BH (Schwarzschild, Kerr,...) are perturbed, they can not emit GW, is that?

Comment: @riemannium You need a time-dependent quadrupole moment. That's a stronger condition than not being a sphere.

Comment: @Andrew But, a rotating oblate BH like a Kerr BH has not a time dependent quadrupole moment, is that? Then, Kerr BH seems to be something different to a mere rotating mass where one should imagine a SHO describing it. Stupid additional question: J in the Kerr BH solution can not be associated to ANY Simple Harmonic Oscillator fundamental frequency $\omega$?

Comment: @riemannium " a rotating oblate BH like a Kerr BH has not a time dependent quadrupole moment, is that?" -- Correct. "Stupid additional question: J in the Kerr BH solution can not be associated to ANY Simple Harmonic Oscillator fundamental frequency ?" -- I am not sure what you mean. I don't associate a SHO with the Kerr BH, but perhaps there is a way to do so! The Kerr BH does have a rotational frequency associated with its angular momentum.

Comment: @Andrew In classical physics, one can asks what should be the rotational frequency in order to be weightless on the surface (equivalently, the density of the body is tied to it, just as GW frequency is tied to orbital frequency and its harmonics). I wonder if there is a SHO related to Kerr BH or maybe a set of 3 SHO (If I am not missed, Kerr BH geodesics are triperiodic!).

Comment: *I wonder if there is a SHO related to Kerr BH.* Yes, an infinite number of them: the quasinormal modes describing hole perturbations, which I mentioned earlier. They are *damped* oscillations; the hole “rings down” to its stable state. Black holes are like bells in that regard. The modes obey the rather miraculous Teukolsky equation.